# Exterior caulking - metal to concrete, metal to metal, metal to painted wood (pacific northwest). Any negatives of dow 795?

Tags: exterior, caulking

I am looking for a long lasting caulking for exterior work.  I have primarily metal cladding but there is metal to metal, metal to concrete and metal to painted wood areas that need caulking.

I reviewed this thread:

https://www.contractortalk.com/threads/best-caulk-sealant-osi-quad-vs-silicone-and-polyurethane.413759/

and it seems like the poly based caulks are prone to uv damage but a lot of people tend to like them.

One comment seemed to suggest that silicone sealant wouldn't work for adhesion to painted wood.  Do I need different caulk for the different areas?

My siding contractor recommends dow 795 which is a silicone sealant.  Anyone have any negative views of dow 795?

Amazon reviews all seem quite good - https://www.amazon.com/Dow-Corning-Silicone-Building-Sealant/product-reviews/B000NY76MI/ref=cm_cr_unknown?filterByStar=five_star&pageNumber=1

Only one comment about it being too soft and damaged by cleaning and one about the cure time being 7-14 days (I am not fused about that).

Comment: Not going to VtC (yet), but this feels very much like a broad, opinion based question. I get where you're coming from, but I'm not sure how to clean it up to fit it into the SE format...

Comment: I agree opinion based: in the PNW UV issues would be the last thing I would worry about compared to the rest of the country.

Comment: Yeah I am less concerned about the UV but if the silicone is just as good and doesn't have that problem then I can be less worried about using it in a place that I likely won't be inspecting in the next 10-20 years or maybe that isn't possible and I just have to accept maintenance with it?  I tried to make the question not opinion based - does dow 795 have negatives, do I need two types of caulk based on material, but a lot of caulks and sealants are new so without evidence I am left to just buy whatever and redo it when it fails

Comment: @Fresh Codemonger- Since this is "opinion based" I will add mine. The only caulking I would use for exterior water sealant these days is a clear urethane caulk (it also comes in various colors)- I use Geocell from ABC supply (no affiliation). It sticks well to most everything and remains flexible and is paintable. Pure silicon caulks seems to easily peel away after time and also seems to attract black mildew and look bad.